# Subdomain names of traducir.win now point to the wrong language

Tags: bug, status-completed, international-sites, translations, traducir

Unlike before, now all subdomains of traducir.win point to the wrong translation language, like this:

- https://es.traducir.win/ -> SOja
- https://ja.traducir.win/ -> SOpt
- https://pt.traducir.win/ -> SOru
- https://ru.traducir.win/ -> SOes

Comment: Well, that is one way to introduce lots of people to a new language ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aaand that's entirely my fault. I moved Traducir to a different server and things looked good... but I gotta confess I didn't pay attention to each site showing the right language.

I have an nginx docker container that acts as a reverse proxy of the app containers... but when I restart the containers, they get their IPs reassigned and nginx keeps on pointing to the old ones.

The fix is... restarting nginx (which I've done and I'm adding to my todo list an item to check that it's part of the normal release).

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Quick question - do we status-review these? Traducir is kinda a strange "quasi official" project? I was considering pinging, but figured you'd twig on

Comment: let's treat it as an official project, we do have plans to transition everything into Stack Overflow's infrastructure before I'm gone :)

Comment: "before I'm gone" :( . But will treat it as such.